# onclick is not calling the javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys I have written a code like this in the script tag of my web page

```
window.reset = function (e, elementId) {
  e.wrap("<form>").closest("form").get(0).reset();
  $(elementId).attr("src", " ").width(30).height(30);
  e.unwrap();
};

window.a = function (e, elementId) {
  e.wrap("<form>").closest("form").get(0).reset();
  $(elementId).attr("src", " ").width(30).height(30);
  e.unwrap();
};
```

Both of the functions do the same work. But the problem is the reset function is not called on click but the 'a' function is called\

What I meant is:

This is the button that calls the reset function. This way the reset is not being called

```
 <button type="button" id="img-refresh" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" 
    onclick="reset($('#image'), '#img-show');"
  > Refresh </button>
```

This way the 'a' method is being called.

```
 <button type="button" id="img-refresh" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" 
    onclick="reset($('#image'), '#img-show');"
  > Refresh </button>
```

When I replace 'reset' with 'a' it is working.
Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Even though I change it like this

```
window.customFunction = {
  reset: function (e, elementId) {
    e.wrap("<form>").closest("form").get(0).reset();
    $(elementId).attr("src", " ").width(30).height(30);
    e.unwrap();
  },
};
```

and use call it like this, It is not working

```
 <button type="button" id="img-refresh" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" 
    onclick="customFunction.reset($('#image'), '#img-show');"
  > Refresh </button>
```

Comment: Why `onclick="reset($('#image'), '#img-show');"` when there's jQuery?

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please more clearly

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `reset` is a reserved word the `window` context... or maybe an other script from your vendros are overwriting your function

My first question is... why are you declaring your functions like that ?

I can suggest 2 options :

You could use a simple function declaration instead of the `window.reset` stuff you did

```js
  function reset() { 
    // do stuff
  }
```

And then use it exactly the same way you already did ?

OR

If you expressly want it in the `window` context, use a parent key to ensure you did not overwrite other functions nor any extarnal script overwrite yours...

```js
window.myCustonFunction = {
  reset: function() {  },
  a: function() { }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to follow the second method. But it did not work

Comment: Take a look at the **EDIT**